# Deprecation warning in Mongoose when connecting to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the code below for connecting to MongoDB:

```
*const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//Connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect('mongobd://localhost/testaroo');
mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
console.log("Connection has been made");
}).on('error', function (error) {
console.log("Connection Error:", error);
});*
```

I am fetching this kind of error:

> DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: look at [this link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5399) for a reference

Comment: it seems to be a bug in the latest version of mongoose..

Comment: Warnings aren't errors. If it works, it works. You can work around it, but the suggested answers to your question may cause more issues than they solve. Look [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5399#issuecomment-322041860) for a solution that will probably work better.

Answer (score 0):

Now your db open method deprecated. so you can try below example

```
/*
 * The file will take care of the database connectivity
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testaroo',{
    useMongoClient: true,
});


//check if we are connected successfully or not
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
```

Comment: Many, if not *all*, of your recent answers have abused the blockquote formatting for sections of text that are not quotations. You should *only* use blockquote formatting when you are quoting someone else's words, or the exact output of a computer. Do not use it for emphasis. You can emphasize text by making it bold. (But please use bold sparingly!)